# Gmail service insert MimeMessage

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api, service-accounts, google-api-java-client

I have  Problem when calling Gmail service to insert a MimeMessage

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId(accountId)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(urlFile))
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(
                            Collections.singleton(GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT))
                    .setServiceAccountUser(accountUser).build();

            Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY,
                    credential).build();
....

message = service.users().messages().insert(accountUser, message)
                    .setDeleted(Boolean.TRUE).execute();
```

I receive a 400 error :

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
> {
> "error" : "invalid_grant",
> "error_description" : "java.security.SignatureException: Invalid signature for token:....
> }

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be something wrong with your [delegation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/smime_certs?hl=en) setup for one you have forgoten to add the google workspace domain user who you wish to delegate as check setServiceAccountUser.

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
  .setTransport(httpTransport)
  .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
  .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
  .setServiceAccountScopes(GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT)
  .setServiceAccountUser(googleWorkspaceDomainUserToDeligateTo)
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
      new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
  .build();
```

That being said this is not the error that i would expect to cause an invalid_grant.  I think thats being caused by the fact that you havent configured the service account properly in Google workspace.

Comment: everything worked fine before with the same User Account/Key (same configuration) , and suddenly we receive this error... can it be related to an expired/deactivated account by Google... ?

Comment: I would check your workspace account if someone changed something in there it may have effected the project.